# Is there a way to replace an HTML variable with a Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask

So I have this variable called "posts" in html and its used in a for loop to create a series of well, posts.

```
   {% for post in posts %}
     {% with  voteform = voteform, votes = votes, post = post %}
       {%include "postlayout.html"%}

     {% endwith %}
   {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

I then use Ajax to retrieve a new querylist from flask and return another series of posts based on what filters the user selects.

```
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){
      all.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(all)
    var moods = {
      'filters': all
    };
    $.ajax({
      url : "/update",
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(moods),
      contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      success: function(resp){
        $('div#response').html('posts <br>')

        for (var key in resp.data) {
          var val = resp.data[key]
          console.log(val)
          $('div#response').append(resp.data[key]['songname'] + ' by ' +
           resp.data[key]['artist'] + '<br>')
      }

        console.log(resp.data)
      },
      error: function(error){
        console.log(error)
      }
     });
    }
```

So I was wondering if there was a way to replace "posts" in my html code with "resp.data" from my json code.

Comment: There are no variables in HTML

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no.

The Flask template is rendered into HTML server-side before the AJAX request is made and so you cant use the AJAX response in your Flask template.

You'll have to use JavaScript (or/and jQuery) to loop over the response data and insert the required HTML.

Comment: dangit. The problem is when I do that, Ajax seems to make everything into an a href, linking to #.

Comment: jQuery **is** javascript.